# strip words out of a character

Tags: r, character, gsub

I have a character, “vars”.

```
vars=c("cogD", "relevel(cbsnivcat3f, \"Lower\")", "relevel(leidingf, \"geen\")", 
"relevel(ocdisf, \"Law\")")
```

I want to get only the words between the “`(`“ and the “`,`” so and up with the words between the bracket and the comma,e.g., `relevel(cbsnivcat3f, \"Lower\")` only  `"cbsnivcat3f"`

my goal is: `vars= c("cogD","cbsnivcat3f","leidingf”,"ocdisf")`

Comment: How did you get `vars`, maybe you should fix your previous step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a regular expression:

```
gsub("relevel\\((.*?), .*", "\\1", vars)
[1] "cogD"        "cbsnivcat3f" "leidingf"    "ocdisf"
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Andrie.  Can you please explain the "\\1" part. Thank you

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php) it contains a syntax overview and a view examples, handy for those want to know what \\1 is.

Answer (score 0):

The `rm_between` function in a `qdapRegex` which I maintain, allows you to grab substrings between a left and right bound.  That would work nicely for this situation.  In the last sstep we replace any `NA`s with the original values.

```
library(qdapRegex)
out <- unlist(rm_between(vars, "(", ",", extract=TRUE))
out[is.na(out)] <- vars[is.na(out)]
out

## [1] "cogD"        "cbsnivcat3f" "leidingf"    "ocdisf"
```

The regular expressiob behind the scenes is: `"(().*?(,)"` which can also be used with base, **stringi** or **stringr** approaches.

Comment: Thank you @Tyler Rinker. Is there an update for qdapRegex that runs on R3.0.2? "qdapRegex’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)"

Comment: I think if you use: `install.packages("qdapRegex", type="source")` it will still install.  If not download the zip/tar.ball and install from source that way.

Comment: Tank you @Tyler Rinker, I'll give it a shot.